# Condition/Decision testing with loops

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

I'm trying to set up a load of test cases for a program, I've managed to create cases for all of the if statements, but the while loops and for loops confuse me a bit as I'm not sure what the test cases should be. I have pseudo code such as:

```
DO for each word (firstword) in textlist
```

and

```
DO while error flag clear and rows left to read
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider conditions that cause zero iterations, one iteration, a few iterations, and a very large number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

For the 'For' and 'While' loop statements, try the Boundary Value Analysis (BVA) and Equivalence partitioning testing approaches. By using these approaches you will be able to create cases for the pending part.

http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-boundary-value-analysis-in-software-testing/

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-boundary-value-analysis-and-equivalence-partitioning/